# Adding every two numbers in a list

Tags: list, random, addition

I have the following problem

```
import random
a_list = range(0,64)
a = random.sample(a_list,16)
print(a)
```

So I get 16 random numbers.

Now what I want further is to add every two numbers in the random set of 16 elements even with each number to be added with itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use just pure python lists, the solution can be a one-liner list comprehension.

```
sums_list = [n+m for n in a for m in a]
```

With Numpy you can use broadcasting.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(a)
sums = arr[:, np.newaxis] + arr[np.newaxis, :]
sums_list = sums.flatten().tolist()
```

Comment: Can you also tell that after getting the list of these sums how can I tell python to give me the missing numbers from our original list ( 0 --63) anf there are no missing numbers return

Comment: You can use set difference: `set(a_list) - set(sums_list)`.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is satisfactory.

Comment: Yes all worked thank you. Appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please write down an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a list of 0 --63 numbers then i want to select any 16 numbers randomly and then i want the list of all sums of two numbers in the random list of 16 numbers and want to check if the sums will give me the original list ( 0 ---63) by usin only the random 16 numbers